# Protecting application from erroneous Lua script

Tags: c, lua, microcontroller, rtos

I am using Lua in a microcontroller project.
My software uses an RTOS, and appart from its other tasks, it also calls a Lua script that the user provides.

The script must have two functions: an `init` function and a `run` function. My application calls the `init` function during initalization, and then calls the `run` function periodically.

The way I load the script is something very similar to `dofile()`.

The `run` function is needed to return. This way the underlying thread yields the processor for the other lower priority threads.

So the question is, how can I protect the system from a user providing a "dangerous" script, i.e. a script that never finishes its initial execution, before I have the chance to call the functions I need. 
See the following:

```
function init
    --Do some stuff.
end

function run
    --Do some other stuff.
end

while (true) do
    --Do nasty stuff, without ever returning.
end
```

On the above example the code blocks during the initial loading of the script, and never returns. I never get the chance to call the `init` and `run` functions. How can I detect such cases, and how to get protected?

**Edit**
Forgot to mention. I am using Lua 5.2.2.

Comment: Do You emebed Lua with own hands, or use ready package? Embedding has all required things, i.e. debugger API, limit libraries etc

Comment: how do you protect yourself from a `while true do end` in init and run?

Comment: Yes I embedded Lua, I didn't use a ready package.

Comment: The init and run functions are protected by software watchdog timers, that are very difficult to start before the script is loaded. It has to load somehow, then configure the rest of the system (based on globals defined in the script), and then start the watchdogs and the functions.

Comment: My imagined solution (different than answers) goes thru C code and Lua API. Isnt' extremely complicated, Lua integration is very well designed, but impossible to write here short :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to defer execution of user script until you have WD ready.

---

Let's assume this is user script:
**user_script.lua**

```lua
function init()
   --Do some stuff.
end

function run()
   --Do some other stuff.
end

while (true) do
   --Do nasty stuff, without ever returning.
end
```

---

**What you are doing now in your host application** (as if it was written on Lua)

```lua
dofile("user_script.lua")

init_watchdog()

init()

run()
run()
```

---

**What you should do in your host application**

```lua
local user_script_as_text = read_content_of_file("user_script.lua")
assert(loadstring(
[[
   function init()  -- this is your wrapper around user script
      init = nil
      do
         ]]..user_script_as_text..
[[  
      end
      init()  -- invoking "init" defined by user
   end
]]
))()

init_watchdog()

init()  -- invoking your wrapper

run()
run()
```

---

If you need to read values of some configuration variables before turning WD on, then those config variables must be provided as an easy-to-parse string like the following `var1=42,var2=on,var3="Hi"`. These config variables can't be in Lua script because Lua script could loop forever.
In other words, you need two files from user: **user_config_vars.json** and **user_script.lua**

Answer (score 1):

Set a line hook or a count hook and abort if it exceeds a limit.

Comment: This was my initial approach. But as I cannot estimate the complexity of the loaded script, my limit would only be so arbitrary. I am afraid eventually valid but complex scripts will be terminated, or the limit would be so high that problematic scripts may still get executed.

Comment: So is there any way for Lua to load everything to its state, functions, globals, etc but not execute anything? Thus I could call the needed functions later...